# A question about two subgroups with coprime orders

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $H,K$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$ with coprime orders, then
$H\cap (xKx^{-1})=\{1\}$ for all $x\in G$ (because $|H\cap K^x|$ divides $\gcd(|H|,|K^x|)=\gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$).

Now, my question is **whether the converse is also true**.

Note that with the assumption we have
$$
|HxK|=|HK^x|=|H||K^x|=|H||K|.
$$
Now, if $X$ denotes a set of (all) representatives of double cosets of $H,K$,
then $|G|=\sum_{x\in X}|HxK|=|H||K||X|$ and so $|H||K|$ divides $|G|$ which is a result weaker than $\gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$.

Comment: Note that $K^x = x^{-1}Kx$, so you may want to keep your conjugation consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with non-normal subgroups is to take $G=S_3\times S_3$, let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $(\tau,e)$ where $\tau$ is a transposition, and let $K$ be the subgroup generated by $(e,\rho)$ where $\rho$ is a transposition. Then $H$ and $K$ both have order $2$, but for all $g\in G$, $gKg^{-1}\subseteq \{e\}\times S_3$, so it intersects $H$ nontrivially. More generally, for any groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, and subgroups $H\leq G_1$ and $K\leq G_2$, you have that $H\times\{e\}$ and $\{e\}\times K$ have the desired property, regardless of the orders of $H$ and $K$.

Even more generally, if $G$ is a group, $N$ is a normal subgrup of $G$, and you pick $H$ and $K$ with $K\leq N$ and $H\cap N=\{e\}$, then $g^{-1}Kg\leq N$ for all $g\in G$, so you will also have $H\cap K^g=\{e\}$ for all $g\in G$, regardless of the orders of $H$ and $K$.

Answer (score 2):

The converse is not true.  Let $G=\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$, with $H$ and $K$ the first and second factors, respectively.

Comment: @-Robert Shore Many thanks. Do you have non-normal examples of such subgroups?

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand Not off the top of my head.